# Under what condition do we have $P\{(X|Y)|Z\} = P\{X | (Y \cap Z)\}$

Tags: probability

It's obvious that when $X,Y,Z$ are independent, we have
$$P\{(X|Y)|Z\} = P\{X | (Y \cap Z)\},$$ 
but if we only have $Y$ and $Z$ are independent, does this equation still holds?

---

Edit:

OK, a bit about how this comes.  I saw an attempt to calculate $P\{X|Y\}$ goes like this
$$
P\{X|Y\} = P\{X|Y \cap Z\}P\{Z\} + P\{X|Y \cap Z^c\}P\{Z^c\}.
$$
My interpretation of this is that
\begin{align*}
& P\{X|Y\} = P\{(X|Y) \cap Z\} + P\{(X|Y) \cap Z^c\} \\
& \; = P\{(X|Y) | Z\}P\{Z\} + P\{(X|Y) | Z^c\}P\{Z^c\} \\
& \; = P\{X|Y \cap Z\}P\{Z\} + P\{X|Y \cap Z^c\}P\{Z^c\}.
\end{align*}

So I was wondering what is the condition to have

$$
P\{ (X|Y) | Z\} = P\{X|Y \cap Z \}
$$

Comment: What are $X$, $Y$, and $Z$? Events? Random variables?

Comment: They are events

Comment: Regarding your edit: see my answer. Your two expressions are actually the same thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only interpretation I can give to the (slightly strange for me) $P\{(X|Y)|Z\}$ notation is "probability of event X given ocurrence of event Y *and* event Z". Which is precisely $P\{X | Y \cap Z\}$; or, as it's more simply and commonly writen, $P(X | Y  Z)$.

No need to ask about independence here.

Answer (score 0):

These events are not exactly the "same thing". In general, if you have a probability distribution $P$ and an event $A$, you can condition on $A$ to get a new probability distribution $P'$.

So in this case you could either condition on $Z$ and to get distribution $P'$, and then condition $P'$ on $Y$ to get distribution $P''$, *or* you could go directly from $P$ to $P''$ by conditioning on $Y \cap Z$.

In either case, you get the same probability distribution at the end.

(If $Y \cap Z$ has probability zero then this may be more complicated...)